# can't understand why display:none doesn't work properly

Tags: jquery

I am trying to code a simple responsive menu, but I just can't get it through. The code "should" work, but it doesn't :(

When on mobile, I set the nav block to `display:none` and used jQuery to slideToggle it, but the nav block is still visible.

Can you please explain why ? What am I doing wrong ?

[the code on CodePen](http://codepen.io/cboom1990/pen/wGXjmq)

Thank you and excuse for this

Comment: This is the correct link [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/cboom1990/pen/wGXjmq)

Comment: @Cornel Nita the element on which you have bind thee click event itself is display none. The element to be clicked should be visible..

Comment: Bind the click event to #logo and you can see it working: $("#logo").click(function() {
        $("#navigation").slideToggle("slow");
      });

Answer (score 3):

Because of [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

`nav#navigation` is more specific than `#navigation` so the display block is applied.